# Metasploit payloads with VPN or proxies?

Tags: vpn, proxy, metasploit, meterpreter

I have purchased VPN with torguard and asked them to forward ports. I run a test on the VPN IP and ports specified, and says ports closed, but they say otherwise in interface. Anyway I create a payload with Msfvenom using LHOST =VPN-I.P? LPORT=specified_ports, and create a listener in msfconsole to listen on the same IP and port.

I do this and get no response when the payload is opened on the "victims" device.

When I use public IP provided by my ISP and port forward in my router configurations, I can get the meterpreter to function fine over WAN, just can't seem to figure it out with the public IP now being a dedicated VPN IP.
Any suggestions/solutions would be much appreciated!